# Button Checkboxes do not save checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I am using bootstrap, and am trying to convert checkboxes into a button that shows when it is pressed or not(checked or not).  If I keep the code showing the checkboxes, it works perfect.  If I keep the code as labelled buttons, the "checked" buttons do not load properly(they do save).

Solved : 
It turns out that I just needed to echo out "btn-group active" for the already active checkboxes.

Checkbox Code w/checkboxes(That works)

```
<div class="btn-group" id="salesman" data-toggle="buttons"></div>
<h5>Salesman :</h5>
<?php
        $salesman = json_decode($invoice['Invoice']['salesman'], true);
        $salesman_names = array(1 => "User1",2 => "User2",3 => "User3",4 => "User4",5 => "User5");
            foreach ($salesman_names AS $i => $name) {
                if ($salesman[$name] == "checked") {
                    echo '<label class="btn btn-default"><input type="checkbox" name="data-invoice-salesman[]" value="'.$i.'" checked/>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$name.'</label>';
                } else {
                    echo '<label class="btn btn-default"><input type="checkbox" name="data-invoice-salesman[]" value="'.$i.'" />&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$name.'</label>';
                }
            }       
        ?>
```

Checkbox Code w/out Checkboxes(that needs fixed?)

```
   <div class="btn-group" id="salesman" data-toggle="buttons">
<h5>Salesman :</h5>
<?php
        $salesman = json_decode($invoice['Invoice']['salesman'], true);
        $salesman_names = array(1 => "User1",2 => "User2",3 => "User3",4 => "User4",5 => "User5");
            foreach ($salesman_names AS $i => $name) {
                if ($salesman[$name] == "checked") {
                    echo '<label class="btn btn-default"><input type="checkbox" name="data-invoice-salesman[]" value="'.$i.'" checked/>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$name.'</label>';
                } else {
                    echo '<label class="btn btn-default"><input type="checkbox" name="data-invoice-salesman[]" value="'.$i.'" />&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$name.'</label>';
                }
            }       
        ?>
```

Comment: Slightly confused.  Your changing from checkboxes to buttons and then your trying to test if a button was 'checked'?

Comment: So if a button is "pressed" i want the checkbox state to say "checked", and save corresponding data.  I also want to be able to reload the form, and "checked" checkboxes (that are buttons) pull up the visual state as needed

Comment: Buttons aren't 'checked'.  That's not a valid state for them.  How are you trying to persist this information?  I guess I should make sure I understand.  When you say 'button' do you mean a button or a radio button?

Comment: an actual button, is there a way to "hide" the checkbox, and pass the data from the button to it via javascript or something?

Comment: Oh, so are there checkboxes -and- buttons?

Comment: yes, the checkbox is enclosed within a "label" that converts it into a button

Comment: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/jquery-checkbox-buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you search a toggle buttons, check example bellow.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-default active">
    <input type="checkbox" checked autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 1 (pre-checked)
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 3
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather you want to link the clicking of a label to the toggling of a checkbox (which could be hidden).

```
<label for="me">
    Blah1
    <input type="checkbox" id="me">
</label>
```

Comment: This is already achieved with the code above.  It links, and SAVES, but when I load the form, the linked label does not display properly

Comment: What do you mean doesn't display properly?  Have you verified that it's correctly attaching the checked attribute to the checkboxes it previously checked?

Comment: Here is the code that is attaching the checked attribute :

Comment: if ($salesman[$name] == "checked") {
     echo '<label class="btn btn-default"><input type="checkbox" checked autocomplete="off" name="data-invoice-salesman[]" value="'.$i.'" />&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$name.'</label>';

Comment: That's the code, but what are the actual results?  Is the html right?  If it isn't then that can point to where something is going wrong.

Comment: Zacharia had the proper code, I needed to change "btn btn-default" and add "active" to it